# 1000hz Bootstrap validation is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, email

I am implementing validation using [1000hz bootstrap validation](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/). Everything is going well except two things-

1). `data-match` is not working even when I enter both passwords same. Here is the code-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/login-reg.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.9.0/validator.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" name="inputPassword" data-minlength="6" id="password" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="password" value="" required>
  <div class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="confirm password" value="" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" required>
  <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I googled it and I got a question referring to similar issue [here](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/340). I looked at the solution provided by `1000hz`, on the same page, and checked my code but can't resolve my issue.
Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

2). It validates email correct when I type only `example@gmail` (this much). Shouldn't it validate `.com` too?

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="email" name="email" id="Email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="email" value="" data-error="Email address is invalid" required>
   <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

I mean an email address is like this `example@gmail.com` so it has three main parts- `before @`, `some text after @`and `.com in the end`. When I type `example@` it shows that "Email is invalid", I agree too but the moment I type `example@g` no alert is shown. Is this the correct way to validate an email address? or am I talking sense? What is the correct way to validate an email address?

PS- please go on the website and try writing `example@` and `example@g`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you wrote
    `data-match="#inputPassword"`

but the "#" sign usually corresponds to the id of an element, not the name. Not sure in your case, but it's worth checking.

2) email validation is quite hard to perform correctly, and this only do the basic checks like `there is a "@" sign somewhere in the middle of the string` . You will have to perform other checks (like if there is a .com) yourself, with some more advanced framework or custom scripts (or only back-end), sorry !

EDIT : source for last claim : 
http://formvalidation.io/validators/emailAddress/#is-ab-valid-email-address

Comment: Yes you are right about `#`. I corrected the name and id attributes. now it works.

Answer (score 0):

It was a little mistake. `data-match` takes the `id` value. The correct code should be -

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" name="Password" data-minlength="6" id="inputPassword" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="password" value="" required>
  <div class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="confirm password" value="" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" required>
  <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```